# JSON consisting of 2 separate Strings

Tags: java, json, jackson

I get some JSON from a server. It looks like this:

```
User.json:
[
{
    "user":"Rene8888",
    "userid":1
},
{
    "user":"Paul1032",
    "userid":2
}
]

Post.json:
{
    "content":"I am a test!",
    "postetby":1,
    "editedby": [
        {"id":1},
        {"id":2}
    ]
}
```

From the server I get 2 separate JSON Strings:
A list of users in User.json
A single post in Post.json

I want to deserialize the user list first. The problem comes with deserializing Post.json. I want to have the "postby" value referencing to a object of user as well as each user that edited the post.

The deserialized Object should look like this:

```
public class User {
    public int id;
    public String username;
}

public class Post {
    public String content;
    public User postedBy;
    public List<User> editedBy;
}
```

Comment: this is simple just parse over all the jsons create User from them and from Post.json assign that post to User

Comment: it should be simple, but I want to do it with jackson because of performance improvements. atm I am parsing it manually, but that is just way to slow (in my real case, over 2 seconds for just a part of the whole complex setup)

Comment: I made it with the jackson stream api - so everything is fine for me now :)

Comment: Could you show your example? You can add it as an answer for your question. Maybe it will help to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good example for JSON parsing with Jackson JsonParser: http://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-streaming-api-to-read-and-write-json/

I just parse the users into objects and put them with the id as the key into a hashmap.  Afterwards I parse the posts. If I get to an ID, I get the user object by the id as the key from the hashmap. It's not as simple as using the ObjectMapper, but it works and is really fast.